# stripe payment - how to suspend a subscription (not cancel)

Tags: stripe-payments

We want to use the stripe payment system.

Our model is based on a weekly fee but billed every 13 weeks. So, the user will initially be billed for 13 weeks at the initial subscription quantity.

Our users will be changing the quantity of the subscription several times over the 13 week billing period and some weeks have subscription level of zero.

Can we set a subscription quantity to zero (0), to suspend the subscription.

For Example

$10 per week per subscription unit

First bill is for 13 weeks, for a total of $130.

At the end of the third (3)  week, the customer increase subscription quality to 3, for a weekly charge of $30.

At the end of the sixth (6)  week, the customer decrease subscription quality to 0, for a weekly charge of $0.

At the end of the nineth (9) week, the customer increase subscription quality to 4, for a weekly charge of $40.

So, the second charge (after 13 weeks) is:

1. Bill 13 weeks in advance at the current subscription quantity 4: $40 * 13 weeks = $520
2. Prorate charges

   - 3 weeks * ($30 - $10 (prepaid)) = $60
   - 3 weeks * ($0 - $10 (prepaid)) = -$30 (credit)
   - 4 weeks * ($40 - $10 (prepaid)) = $120

Total Charge:  $670 = 520 + 60 - 30 + 120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the math will work out exactly like you laid it out here, but you can definitely handle stuff like this with Stripe. There's a lot of material on the support site and API docs about proration.

- [Some basics about proration](https://support.stripe.com/questions/handling-subscription-changes)
- [Integration guide section on `quantity`](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#setting-quantities)
- [The update subscription API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription) which has a bit at the bottom about how proration works

So in short, yes, you should be able to do what you're suggesting.